# Only download first file matched by pattern using Wget

Tags: files, wget, download, installer-anaconda

I am trying to retrieve [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution)'s [install script](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2023.03-Linux-x86_64.sh) for automated installation of it in my dotfiles. I want to retrieve the latest version of their installer script(`Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh`) from their [website](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) without hardcoding the version number in the URL. Running

```bash
wget -r repo.anaconda.com/archive -A "Anaconda*-****.**-Linux-x86_64.sh"
```

downloads that file(the first result), but also other files that match the wildcard pattern I used. How do I make sure that only the first file I want gets downloaded?

Comment: Yes, can you be more specific and add sample input/expected output and a test URL ?

Comment: Sure. I am trying to automate the download of [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution)(a Python distribution) in my dotfiles. I want to retrieve the latest version of its install script from their [website](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/). The most current script is called `Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh`. Running ` wget -r https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/ -A "Anaconda*-****.**-Linux-x86_64.sh"` downloads that file(it is the first occurrence of the pattern) and another files that match the pattern. My expected output is having only the one file I want downloaded.

Comment: Added full working example of getting the last anaconda

Comment: Please update your question to include an example of what you're trying to achieve. Don't put updates in the comments as they can be all too easily missed or even deleted without notice

Comment: Thank you for the tip, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Using `mech-dump --links`:

```
mech-dump --links https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736061/ |
    grep -m1 favicon |
    xargs wget -O favicon.ico
```

`mech-dump` is instaled with the [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) module [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) or Debian package `libwww-mechanize-perl`

##### Using Thomas E. Dickey's [lynx](/questions/tagged/lynx):

To fetch the last `anaconda` release:

```
lynx \
    --listonly \
    --nonumbers  \
    --dump https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution |
    grep -m1 -F 'Linux-x86_64.sh' |
    xargs wget
```

If you trust the source, to execute the script *on the fly* : `... | xargs wget -O - | sh`

Comment: I am astonished by the conciseness of your answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you do not mind, what would be the best approach to executing the script after it is downloaded? Can I pipe the file name to bash? One easy but not very clean approach is using `wget` with the `-O` flag to specify a filename and running it like that.

Comment: If you trust the source: `... | xargs wget -O - | bash`

Comment: I was wondering what is the empty flag(`- `) for?

Comment: Print on `/dev/stdout`

Comment: Is this used as the argument for the `-O` flag or just to pipe the file name? Edit: I saw your edit, I see what you mean now.

Comment: Is the empty flag universal for Unix programs or specific to `wget`? I do not see anything specific to `wget` in its man page

Comment: With `wget` in this case it means to print to STDOUT. In other cases, it means to read from `/dev/stdin`. Consider this example: `cat xml | xmllint --xpath '/' -`

Comment: I see. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: `LESS='+/wget -O -' man wget`